# SSRS Report - How to make parameter flexible

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi, reporting

I want the SSRS report have flexible parameter.

Example, got two parameter as OTP No (Text field) and Branch Code(multiple values from dropdown).

If want to search based on OTP No, report should only search based on OTP No.

Same goes to Branch Code if want to search based on Branch Code, report should only search based on Branch Code.
If both parameter got value, then report should search both field A and field B.

**Below is my query.**

```sql
where ((@otpNo ='' ) and (@branchCode is not null) and (branch_code in (@branchCode))) 
or ((@branchCode is null) and (@otpNo is not null) and (otp_no = @otpNo))
or ((@otpNo is not null) and (@branchCode is null) and (otp_no = @otpNo) and (branch_code in (@branchCode)))
```

However I encountered error on this and I suspect branch code is multi values which cause my query not working.

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over 2 years; it is long past you got your upgrade path sorted out.

Comment: For a query such as the above, you are likely better off using a stored procedure.

Comment: Currently SQL server is 2016. Kindly further elaborate what you means better off using a stored procedure?

Comment: Why did you tag [[tag:sql-server-2008]] and [[tag:ssrs-2008-r2]] then? As far as I know as well, [[tag:powerbi]] isn't compatible with those versions. Tag properly.

Comment: Updated the tag. can you advise what you means better off using a stored procedure?

Comment: As in, use SSRS to call a Procedure on your instance, rather than an inline `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the branch code send all the values (if the user doesn't want to filter for a specific one) to make the query simpler.

```
where 
   (NULLIF(@otpNo, '') IS NULL OR otpNo = @otpNo) AND
   branch_code IN (@branchCode)
```

Comment: You are right..user branch code should send all values if dun want filter specific...Thanks for the enlighten...